# How to use Java Streams to merge member of type list in object, such that we get a single list

Tags: java, java-stream, compiler-optimization

I have a list of rule infos, each of which has a list of sub-rules. Now I want to get a list of sub-rule ids with a particular type. I wrote following for the same.

```
ruleInfosList.stream()
   .flatMap(ruleInfo -> ruleInfo.getSubRuleInfosList().stream())
   .filter(subRuleInfo -> subRuleInfo.getSubRuleTypesList().contains(ruleType))
   .map(subRuleInfo::getRuleId)
   .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableList())
```

I think this method is clean but being new I wanted to know if this is an overkill, and the impact on the performance since I would be iterating thrice here. If there is a better yet clean way to do so.

I also wanted to know if there are some compile time optimizations happening which takes care of this? If not why what's issue in having such an optimization pass.

Comment: If the `getRuleId` is unique for each `subRuleInfo`, there is nothing wrong here that comes up. The only possible micro-optimisation via normal iterations could have been converting `subRuleInfo.getSubRuleTypesList()` to a `Set` before performing `contains`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are not iterating three times here, Java 8 streams are optimized in the way that every element will get operated on by the stream operations you want **independent of the status of other elements**, unless it's absolutely required that status of other elements is known. This is the benefit of parallelism in Java 8 streams.

So in your case it doesn't matter to the one element of ruleInfosList where the other element(s) are along the stream, it can be processed through the flatmap, filter and then map operations of the stream.

What could be the cases where it's absolutely required that status of other elements is known?
Consider operations like sorted(), where all the elements are required to be processed right uptill these steps for these functions to work. Formally, it will only happen for a subset of stateful operations.